# Agent does not set "From" in header

Tags: lotus-notes

We have a mail agent which generates a basic mail and sends it to an mailaddress.

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
Dim db As NotesDatabase

Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Set maildoc = New NotesDocument(db)

maildoc.Form = "Memo"
maildoc.SendTo = "test123@web.de"
maildoc.Subject = "Test"
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("Principal","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("AltFrom","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("InetPrincipal","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("SMTPOriginator","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("From","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("sentFrom","testFrom@anydomain.de")
Call maildoc.replaceitemvalue("InetFrom","testFrom@anydomain.de")

Call maildoc.send(False,False)
```

When I execute this agent and look in my web.de account I see that there are not senders information. In the header of the mail there is no "from" field set. Only a "Sender" field.

Does anyone know about a server configuration or something to solve this? I don´t think it´s the agents fault, right?

Comment: Try setting Principal to "testFrom@anydomain.de@DOMINODOMAIN". So if your Domino domain is called Domain, then set it to "testFrom@anydomain.de@Domain"

Comment: then the mail is not sent at all

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It works now. Provide it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Principal to "testFrom@anydomain.de@DOMINODOMAIN".

So if your Domino domain is called Domain, then set it to "testFrom@anydomain.de@Domain"

Comment: Maybe one more Question: Is it possible to configure the server to automatically use the Domino Domain? Or is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: I only know of this "hack" and use it in several applications

Comment: It is not a hack, it is by design. Domino decides for itself who sends the mail, which is either the person who creates the mail or the person who signed the agent. So, if you sign the agent differently, e.g. by a generic person who owns a group mail database, that person will be the sender when the agent is used. Real hacks are: putting the mail directly into the mail.box database, and writing your own AddIn DLL.